# ERROR: a stop job is running for MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sleep, mode

This error occurs only when I try to shutdown my pc, that was before in sleep mode
Then my pc cannot shutdown with the following error message:

> ```
> a stop job is running for MySQL server
> ```

When I issue stop service command before sleep everything is ok

System: OpenSuse Tumbleweed
Linux my.site 4.18.11-1-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 29 11:29:05 UTC 2018 (4a5c1c1) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

MariaDB mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.18-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/892026/shutdown-hangs-on-a-stop-job-is-running-to-for-mysql-community-server-on-ubunt

Comment: Didn't helped much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the problem solved with kernel 4.19.